# Specify number of decimal places in SQL

Tags: sql

When running a query in SQL and defining a new value, how do I set the number of decimal places I want to see on that value?

E.g.

Table1:

```
FigureA, FigureB
.23423, .52342
```

Query:

```
Select FigureA, FigureB, (FigureA-FigureB) As difference From Table1
```

But I only want "difference" to be to two decimal places.

Comment: The easiest way is:  `cast(FigureA - FibureB as decimal(10, 2))`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Doesn't that do the wrong thing for `.101-.052`? (Gives 4 instead of 5). I think he wants `cast(FigureA as decimal(10,2) - cast(FigureB as decimal(10,2)`

Comment: @Hogan . . . Actually, I don't know.  And I don't know if the OP wants to round up or truncate.  That's why I gave the suggestion as a comment rather than an answer.